# Openpyxl: AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'cell'

Tags: python, openpyxl

So I'm trying to make my code print a certain column by inputting different cells. So i designed my code to make a person enter five different types of movies and then openpyxl iterates through the excel file, looks for the five movies and prints out the whole row but the thing is it keeps spitting back an error and I don't know how to fix it

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Shay/PycharmProjects/untitled/Assignment ITN.py", line 39, in <module>
   listcreator(movieID)
File "C:/Users/Shay/PycharmProjects/untitled/Assignment ITN.py", line 28, in listcreator
   if sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value == movieOne:
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'cell'
```

this is my code:

```
import csv
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

movieID = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="C:/Users/Shay/Downloads/Movie IDs - Student Copy.xlsx")
movie_ID = movieID.active


movie_ID_List = []
movie_Ratings_list = []
mveavg = []

movieOne = input("Type first Movie\n")
movieTwo = input("Type in second movie\n")
movieThree = input("Type in third movie\n")
movieFour = input("Type in fourth movie\n")
movieFive = input("Type in fifth movie\n")

movieOneList = []
movieTwoList = []
movieThreeList = []
movieFourList = []
movieFiveList = []

def listcreator(sheet):
    for r in range(1, 27278):
        for c in range(1,2):
            if sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value == movieOne:
                movieOneList.append(sheet.cell(row=r, column=0))
            if sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value == movieTwo:
                movieTwoList.append(sheet.cell(row=r, column=0))
            if sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value == movieThree:
                movieThreeList.append(sheet.cell(row=r, column=0))
            if sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value == movieFour:
                movieFourList.append(sheet.cell(row=r, column=0))
            if sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value == movieFive:
                movieFiveList.append(sheet.cell(row=r, column=0))

listcreator(movieID)

print(movieOneList)
print(movieTwoList)
print(movieThreeList)
print(movieFourList)
print(movieFiveList)
movieOneList - (movieOneList[0])
movieTwoList - (movieTwoList[0])
movieThreeList - (movieThreeList[0])
movieFourList - (movieFourList[0])
movieFiveList - (movieFiveList[0])
print(movieOneList)
print(movieTwoList)
print(movieThreeList)
print(movieFourList)
print(movieFiveList)
```

I should also mention that I am a noob coder so I'm sorry if this question seems really basic but would love the help

Answer (score 2):

You should give your variables better names.

The `listcreator` function takes a Worksheet object. But when you call it, you are passing `movieID`, which is the Workbook object you load at the top, instead of `movie_ID`, which is the active sheet in that book.

If you called these objects something more appropriate, you would have been able to see more easily what you had done wrong.